# Not able to install windows builder on eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Tried installing windows builder by :

1. Searching windowbuilder on eclipse market place that continously throws the following error : "No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/."
2. By ussing add new software option and providing this uRL "http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/1.9.1". It throws following error  "Could not find http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/1.9.1"

Comment: On Windows, Linux or macOS? Where/how is the error displayed? `http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/`works for me with Eclipse 2018-09 (Oxygen is outdated).

Comment: Its windows 64 bit machine with win10 oS @how

Comment: altough oxygen is outdated, can't i put WB plugin on it? @howlger

Comment: Maybe your issue is caused by an already fixed bug. I cannot reproduce this issue on Windows 10 with Eclipse 2018-09. Are you behind a proxy? As a software developer, what would you say to the users of your software that don't want to upgrade and that complain about bugs that have already been fixed?